# c++ Threads and promises

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a thread safe queue which is prepopulated with work by the main thread; when I launch my worker threads they pop a task from the work queue, but also, can push a new task back to the work queue. Brief glimpse into code:

```
auto work_queue = safe_queue{};

static void handle_task(T task) {
  // process the task
  // might push a new task to a work queue using work_queue.push()
}

int main() {
  //some work is done to prepopulate work_queue

  auto handle_work = [](){
    while (!work_queue.empty) {
      T task = work_queue.pop();
      handle_task(task);
    }
  };

  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS; i++) {
    threads.push_back(std::thread(processing));
  }

  std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), [](std::thread &t) {
    t.join();
  }
}
```

I understand that this code won't work correctly since in some cases, queue might be empty while some worker threads are processing work when another thread comes in, doesn't find work and exits (although threads processing tasks might push back new work to queue). My question is, how to prevent threads from exiting prematurely like that? Would that work using `std::promise<void>` to allow threads to communicate to other threads that they still might be working? If so, how would that work with multiple threads (I'm new to c++ and only used promises with single thread)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, that `std::promise<void>` can be used here, since it is more of a one-shot thing. After the result is set in the future, it cannot be unset and hence we cannot wait twice for the same promise.

One can do the following (the counter has to be made thread safe, but I was to lazy to do that right now):

```cpp
int finished_threads = 0;
auto handle_work = [&finished_threads](){
    bool this_finished = false;
    while (finished_threads < NUM_OF_THREADS) {
      while (!work_queue.empty) {
        if(this_finished) {
          this_finished = false;
          --finished_threads;  // evil
        }
        T task = work_queue.pop();
        handle_task(task);
      }
      if(!this_finished) {
        this_finished = true;
        ++finished_threads; // evil
      }
    }
  };
```

This should only exit after all threads have finished (as in: They don't handle a task anymore and there is non in the queue). Then no new task will be put in the queue anymore. The local variable minimizes the access to shared memory.

Please be advised that my experience in multi-threading programming is very limited.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin I took this part of the code from OP so I assumed they thought about that. I think there is a not missing in your comment and I am a bit unsure where.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin work_queue here is thread safe queue, I just didn't include the code for the safe_queue struct which is the thread safe version of queue.

Comment: @n314159 That makes sense, thank you. Can I ask why lines where you increment/decrement finished_threads are marked as 'evil'?

Comment: Because they are not thread safe, since the variable is shared but the access is not synchronised. Probably an atomic will fix this. But I am not exactly sure how you ensure that there is no pop from your queue between one thread checks if it is empty and it pops from it. If you synchronise this block than the increment should be safe as well. Thinking about it maybe you want to change your code such that the popping is done by one thread which then fires worker threads to execute `handle_task`

Comment: @meriam Be aware of that, because `thread safe` does not guarantee everything. For example, the queue has one task in it. `Thread A` checks `empty`, and gets `false`. Then `Thread B` checks `empty`, also gets `false`.  So both threads try to pop, but there is only a single task in the queue! Also, a naive while loop can be [resource hogging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting)...

Comment: @KaenbyouRin I have thread safe empty(), which only allows for one thread at the time to check whether the queue is empty.  By naive looping, are you referring to the while(!work_queue.empty())?

Answer (score 1):

I tried something completely different with an `std::condition_variable`:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <optional>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr int NUM_OF_THREADS = 5;
std::condition_variable input_cv;
std::condition_variable callback_cv;
std::optional<int> data {};
std::mutex m;
std::mutex callback_mutex;
int finished_threads = 0;

static void handle_task(int i)
{
}

struct worker 
{
    const int num;
    worker () = delete;
    void operator()() {
        while(true){
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
            ++finished_threads; // protected by m
            callback_cv.notify_one(); // wake up main thread if it sleeps
            input_cv.wait(lk);
            if(!data)
                return;
            --finished_threads; // protected by m
            int local_data = *data;
            lk.unlock();

            handle_task(local_data);
        }
    }
};


struct safe_queue // dummy
{
    int pop () const { return 0; }
    bool empty() const {return true;}
};

void main_thread ()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    safe_queue work_queue;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        workers.emplace_back(worker{i});
    }

    do
    {
        do
        {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
                data.emplace(work_queue.pop());
            }
            input_cv.notify_one();
        } while(!work_queue.empty() && finished_threads > 0)
        // If no thread has finished, we can wait for the next one to finish.

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(callback_mutex);
        callback_cv.wait(lk); // We wait on some thread to have finished
    }while(finished_threads < NUM_OF_THREADS && !work_queue.empty()); // In either case, there remains something to do.

    data = {};
    input_cv.notify_all();

    std::for_each(begin(workers), end(workers), [](std::thread &t) { t.join();});
}


int main()
{

    std::thread t(main_thread);

    t.join();

}
```

Not sure if it is better, but it is certainly more complicated^^.

Comment: Is it the same as implementing thread safe pop() and push() in the safe_queue itself? Because that's what I have right now - in the pop(), I wait until the queue becomes non empty and in the push() I push the task and use condition variable to notify some thread waiting to pop (both include locking of course).

Comment: This also ensures that all threads are working when there is work and no ine exits prematurely. I think, at least^^